# Jetpack Compose Switch onCheckedChange method gets triggered automatically without user interaction

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack compose Switch composable function. The onCheckedChange lambda gets called occasionally. This case is not always reproducible. When I checked inside the method, I noticed that onCheckedChange lambda is called from rememberSwipeableStateFor method from the DisposableEffect.

Note :-

- I've used it inside Android's ListView as an item.
- The list view is present in a navigation drawer.

Comment: Kindly provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)